# Why is my Toyota Sienna wobbling from side to side

Tags: toyota, steering, shaking, sienna

I have a 2007 Toyota Sienna with 85,000 miles. This past summer while driving on the highway the engine light went on and it started shaking violently. Pressing on the accelerator gave barely a response above 50 mph. I shifted down to about 2nd or third gear, which seemed to help a little, but still couldn't get it to go much faster than 50 or so. I dropped off the family, shutting the engine while doing so. Around ten minutes later I started it up to head to a mechanic and no sign of trouble. When I got there, my computer wouldn't let itself be read, and that was the end of that. Weird experience, but that's what happened.
Ever since then though I have been experiencing this weird side to side motion while accelerating between 40 and sixty mph. At 60 it is still there but not nearly as bad.

I replaced a ball joint which was bad in the hopes that this would alleviate the problem.

I also replaced all four tires and had the properly balanced.

Still the problem persists. I've searched the web & it seems that the shaking is not so uncommon, with limited reports of possibly fixing it. However no one seems to have experienced the violent shaking and engine light.

Anyone have any advice?

Comment: Did you resolve this issue? If so, we'd love to hear about it! If not, we can only guess the reason for the engine light if you are unable to connect to the computer. In any case, please advise,

Comment: It appears the wobble was not connected to the stall. The stall never happened again, thankfully. The wobble continued on, never being properly diagnosed until finally the right axle broke and was replaced. All is well now. I had read about people replacing seemingly good axle arms in an attempt to fix this apparently common issue with siennas.