# Toyota vibrates/shakes when accelerating over 30 mph

Tags: vibration, sienna

I have a 2005 sienna, it vibrates really badly when accelerating over about 40.  Kind of like shaking the vehicle left to right, like a really bad wheel balance. When coasting it seems OK.  So I don't think it's the wheels.

Comment: Same as https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/12735/why-is-my-toyota-sienna-wobbling-from-side-to-side apparently, but couldn't add an answer there...

Answer (score 1):

Took it to a shop, guy grabbed the CV axles and said "whoa, those seem loose!"

Replaced the passenger CV axle (which had a torn boot so I assumed was in worse shape).  Replacing it was [non trivial](https://www.siennachat.com/threads/passenger-cv-axle-boot-torn.60339/page-2).

Works much better now.

Comment: Definitely a challenge, especially your first time.